# How to parse fixed width string with complex rules into component fields with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse fixed width records using c# and Regular Expressions.
Each record contains a number of fixed width fields, with each field potentially having non-trivial validation rules. The problem I'm having is with a match being applied across the fixed width field boundaries.

Without the rules it is easy to break apart a fixed width string of length 13 into 4 parts like this:

```
(?=^.{13}$).{1}.{5}.{6}.{1}
```

Here is a sample field rule:
Field can be all spaces OR start with [A-Z] and be right padded with spaces. Spaces cannot occur between letters

If the field was the only thing I have to validate I could use this:

```
(?=^[A-Z ]{5}$)([ ]{5}|[A-Z]+[ ]*)
```

When I add this validation as part of a longer list I have to remove the ^ and $ from the lookahead and I start to get matches that are not of length 5.

Here is the full regex along with some sample text that should match and not match the expression.

```
(?=^[A-Z ]{13}$)A(?=[A-Z ]{5})([ ]{5}|(?>[A-Z]{1,5})[ ]{0,4})(?=[A-Z ]{6})([ ]{6}|(?>[A-Z]{1,6})[ ]{0,5})Z
```

How do I implement the rules so that, for each field, the immediate next XX characters are used for the match and ensure that matches do not overlap?

Lines that should match:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLZ
A           Z
AB          Z
A     G     Z
AB    G     Z
ABCDEF      Z
ABCDEFG     Z
A     GHIJKLZ
AB    GHIJKLZ
```

Lines that should not match:

```
AB D        Z
AB D F      Z
AB   F      Z
A     G I   Z
A     G I  LZ
A     G    LZ
AB   FG    LZ
AB D FG     Z
AB   FG I   Z
AB D FG i   Z
```

The following 3 should not match but do.

```
AB   FG     Z
AB   FGH    Z
AB  EFGH    Z
```

---

#### EDIT:

**General solution** (based on Ωmega's answer) with named captures for clarity:

```
(?<F1>F1Regex)(?<=^.{Len(F1)})
(?<F2>F2Regex)(?<=^.{Len(F1+F2)})
(?<F3>F3Regex)(?<=^.{Len(F1+F2+F3)})
               ...
(?<Fn>FnRegex)
```

Another example: Spaces between regex and zero-width positive lookback (?<= are for clarity.

```
(?<F1>\d{2})    (?<=^.{2})
(?<F2>[A-Z]{5}) (?<=^.{7})
(?<F3>\d{4})    (?<=^.{11})
(?<F4>[A-Z]{6}) (?<=^.{17})
(?<F5>\d{4})
```

Comment: When working with .Net Regex class, I recommend this tool http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: I have posted how to solve the problem using one single regex, to your specific case. If you find more difficulties, just let us know. =)

Comment: @Ωmega has a much simpler single-regex than mine... I think it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible to validate it by single regex pattern

```
^[A-Z ][A-Z]*[ ]*(?<=^.{6})[A-Z]*[ ]*(?<=^.{12})[A-Z ]$
```

If you need also capture all such groups, use

```
^([A-Z ])([A-Z]*[ ]*)(?<=^.{6})([A-Z]*[ ]*)(?<=^.{12})([A-Z ])$
```

Comment: @JayWalker : If you need to extract the values of the fields: `^[A-Z ]([A-Z]*[ ]*)(?<=^.{6})([A-Z]*[ ]*)(?<=^.{12})[A-Z ]$`.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo - Question asks for validation, and even the OP's code does not show any signs of capturing, so I believe my answer is exactly what he is asking for...

Comment: I see, but the OP regex did have captures... maybe he is not only validating.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo - I have updated the answer with capture groups for all 4 parts, so in case OP wants that...

Answer (score 1):

If the input string is fixed in size, then you can match a specific position using look-aheads and look-behinds, like this:

```
(?<=^.{s})(?<fieldName>.*)(?=.{e}$)
```

where:

- s = start position
- e = string length - match length - s

If you concatenate multiple regexes, like this one, then you will get all the fields with specific positioning.

**Example**

- Fixed length: 10
- Field 1: start 0, length 3
- Field 2: start 3, length 5
- Field 3: start 8, length 2

Use this regex, ignoring white spaces:

```
var match = Regex.Match("0123456789", @"
    (?<=^.{0})(?<name1>.*)(?=.{7}$)
    (?<=^.{3})(?<name2>.*)(?=.{2}$)
    (?<=^.{8})(?<name3>.*)(?=.{0}$)",
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)

var field1 = match.Groups["name1"].Value;
var field2 = match.Groups["name2"].Value;
var field3 = match.Groups["name3"].Value;
```

You can place whatever rule you want to match the fields.

I used `.*` for all of them, but you can place anything there.

**Example 2**

```
var match = Regex.Match(" 1a any-8888", @"
    (?<=^.{0})(?<name1>\s*\d*[a-zA-Z])(?=.{9}$)
    (?<=^.{3})(?<name2>.*)(?=.{4}$)
    (?<=^.{8})(?<name3>(?<D>\d)\k<D>*)(?=.{0}$)
    ",
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)

var field1 = match.Groups["name1"].Value; // " 1a"
var field2 = match.Groups["name2"].Value; // " any-"
var field3 = match.Groups["name3"].Value; // "8888"
```

**Here is your regex**

I tested all of them, but the this sample is with the one you said should not pass, but passed... this time, it won't pass:

```
var match = Regex.Match("AB   FG     Z", @"
    ^A
    (?<=^.{1})  (?<name1>([ ]{5}|(?>[A-Z]{1,5})[ ]{0,4}))  (?=.{7}$)
    (?<=^.{6})  (?<name2>([ ]{6}|(?>[A-Z]{1,6})[ ]{0,5}))  (?=.{1}$)
    Z$
    ",
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)

// no match with this input string
```

Comment: Miguel, your solution is very nice as it can be applied for any number of fields (my actual problem has 11).

Answer (score 1):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(
  Regex.Replace(text, @"^(.)(.{5})(.{6})(.)$", "$1,$2,$3,$4"),
  @"^[A-Z ],[A-Z]*[ ]*,[A-Z]*[ ]*,[A-Z ]$");
```

Check this code **[here](http://ideone.com/PygriG)**.

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted this before, but this answer is more specific to your question, and not generalized.

This solves all the cases you have presented in your question, the way you wanted.

**Program to test all cases in your question**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var strMatch = new string[]
                      {
                          // Lines that should match:
                          "ABCDEFGHIJKLZ",
                          "A           Z",
                          "AB          Z",
                          "A     G     Z",
                          "AB    G     Z",
                          "ABCDEF      Z",
                          "ABCDEFG     Z",
                          "A     GHIJKLZ",
                          "AB    GHIJKLZ",
                      };


        var strNotMatch = new string[]
                      {
                          // Lines that should not match:
                          "AB D        Z",
                          "AB D F      Z",
                          "AB   F      Z",
                          "A     G I   Z",
                          "A     G I  LZ",
                          "A     G    LZ",
                          "AB   FG    LZ",
                          "AB D FG     Z",
                          "AB   FG I   Z",
                          "AB D FG i   Z",

                          // The following 3 should not match but do.
                          "AB   FG     Z",
                          "AB   FGH    Z",
                          "AB  EFGH    Z",
                      };

        var pattern = @"
                ^A
                (?<=^.{1})  (?<name1>([ ]{5}|(?>[A-Z]{1,5})[ ]{0,4}))  (?=.{7}$)
                (?<=^.{6})  (?<name2>([ ]{6}|(?>[A-Z]{1,6})[ ]{0,5}))  (?=.{1}$)
                Z$
                ";

        foreach (var eachStrThatMustMatch in strMatch)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(eachStrThatMustMatch,
                pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

            if (!match.Success)
                throw new Exception("Should match.");
        }


        foreach (var eachStrThatMustNotMatch in strNotMatch)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(eachStrThatMustNotMatch,
                pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

            if (match.Success)
                throw new Exception("Should match.");
        }
    }
}
```