# Code to reformat file

Tags: c#, parsing

Need help formatting a seperated .txt file in C#. I have a text file that contains a directory listing and looks like as follows when I open up in notepad or ultra-edit. First column is date and time, next column is the size of file in bytes, third column is the username and fourth column is the name of the file.  Each column is separated by one or more spaces, and the filename column at the end can contain spaces in the filename. They consist of more directories and the total amount of lines in the file is about 200,000.

> Directory of V:\word 
>   01/10/2013   12:30 PM             23,000   BUILTIN/ADMINISTRATOR     FILE NAME.XLS 
>   10/25/2013   10:39 AM        1,332,432   AMERICAS/DOEJ                     FILENAME2.CSV 
>   11/31/2000   09:54 PM      21,999,999   AMERICAS/DOEF                  F_I_L_E_N_A_M_E_4.PDF 
>    Directory of V:\word\administrators 
>   01/10/2013   12:30 PM             23,000   BUILTIN/ADMINISTRATOR     FILENAME.XLS 
>   10/25/2013   10:39 AM        1,332,432   AMERICAS/DOEJ                     FILENAME2.CSV 
>   11/31/2000   09:54 PM      21,999,999   AMERICAS/DOEF                  F_I_L_E_N_A_M_E_4.PDF

My goal is to try and add the path of the directory (ex. V:\Word or other directories) in a fixed format at the end of the filename. So Once you see the "Directory V:\word" then you know every line after and up until a new Directory, should show that path at the end of the filename. This would be considered the fifth column.

Here is some code, but I still need to help. I am able to get V:\word at the end of the file, but how do I read the new directory and append that to the end of the lines for all subsequent lines?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sbText = new StringBuilder(10000);

        string currLine = " Directory of V:\\word ";

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\V.txt"))
            {
                while (!Reader.EndOfStream)
                {

                    if (currLine != " Directory of V:\\word ")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No Directory");

                    }
                    else
                    {                            
                        sbText.AppendLine(Reader.ReadLine() + "V:\\word");
                    }


                }
                // When all of the data has been loaded, write it to the text box in one fell swoop
                richTextBox1.Text = sbText.ToString();

                using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\NEWFILE.txt"))
                {
                    Writer.WriteLine(sbText);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occured. " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Do you control how the text files are generated and written? If so, use tab characters and newline\carriage returns. Make sure your RichTextBox is wide enough to display your text correctly.

Comment: Are those tabs or spaces in between columns.  Also, could you review your description of how the directory name behaves?  Does it apply to all lines before or after it occurs?

Comment: The `Reader.ReadLine()` eats the CR/LF. You can add it back by using StringBuilder's `AppendLine` rather than `Append`.

Comment: @Cameron - I pulled the list from MS-DOS (dir /a/q/s) which is how the file was generated. Then with the use of an old tool foxpro I was able to edit the file as you see in the example. STW - I Assume the spaces between the columns are tabs. And the behavior of the directory applies to the filenames after the fact. So basically the Directory is the header for those specified lines under it, up until a new Directory.

Comment: @dolm77 - if you're getting it from DOS (by redirecting output to a file), then you have spaces, not tabs between the columns of data. Some methods of grabbing the `dir` output may have a hard CR/LF placed at the 80 char point of long lines, which you would have to fix up. Redirecting to a text file will not have that issue. Since it uses space, the easiest solution to retain the column formatting is to use a fixed font like Courier for your RichTextBox.

Comment: @hatchet -- you're correct, it's a space seperated file with columns at fixed positions.  I updated the sample to be more representative.  I'm deleting most comments from my answer since they're noise--you may want to do the same with yours

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly straight-forward approach--which defines a simple class that represents your data, and parses each line into a class instance.  It's efficient, and the results can easily be written to a new file, queried, or displayed:

```
void Main()
{
  var lines = ReadFile();

  lines.ToList().ForEach (Console.WriteLine);
}

IEnumerable<Line> ReadFile()
{
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"file.txt")))
  {
    const string directoryPrefix = " Directory of ";
    Regex splittingRegex = new Regex(@"\s+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    string directory = null;
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      line = line.TrimEnd();
      if (line.StartsWith(directoryPrefix))
      {
        directory = line.Substring(directoryPrefix.Length);
        continue;
      }

      // The "6" parameter means the regex will split the string into 6 parts at most--leaving the last column (filename) unsplit
      var lineParts = splittingRegex.Split(line, 6);
      yield return new Line{ Date = lineParts[0], Time = lineParts[1], Period = lineParts[2], Bytes = lineParts[3], User = lineParts[4], Filename = Path.Combine(directory, lineParts[5]) };
     }
  }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Line
{
  public string Date{get;set;}
  public string Time {get;set;}
  public string Period {get;set;}
  public string Bytes {get;set;}
  public string User {get;set;}
  public string Filename {get;set;}  
}
```

**Note:** This is derived from a couple helper methods for parsing simple text files.  One of [my earlier revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18472544/1) include the helper methods, which might be of use to you (but aren't quite suited for this due to the need to remember the `directory` value).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36359/discussion-between-stw-and-dolm77)

Comment: If it is a fixed width file format you could still use regex and lookbacks to parse the columns. See this SO for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990935/how-to-parse-fixed-width-string-with-complex-rules-into-component-fields-with-re

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing `wCurrLine` but never resetting it. I think you want to reset it after each directory?

You're not incrementing `totalLines`, but then displaying it in label2. I think you should be incrementing it.

How do you check if the input line of text is a directory entry? If your text is consistent as presented, you could check the first letter of each row as it's read in and check if it is the letter 'D'.

You need to `AppendLine` not `Append` to put the carriage returns back in